# GWT library to highlight source code

Tags: gwt, prettify, codehighlighter

I'm trying to find good ready to use gwt library to highlight source code, but I couldn't find any.

Started to think about using http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/ and simple call to JS function after each page rendering but maybe there are some better decisions.